# Count subset of words occurrences in R?

Tags: r, string, text, stringr, sentiment-analysis

In R, suppose I have a list of strings like the following:

```
str_list <- list("corn is food", "corn is good")
```

If I want to count the number of times each word in some **subset of words** like "corn" and "food" occur in each element, is there any way to do this? For example, based on **str_list**, I would want a vector **[2, 1]** that counted food (1x) and corn (1x) in the first element, and corn (1x) in the second element. I do NOT want to count just a single word like "corn", which can just be done with the `stringr::str_count()` function).

Comment: Which package is the `str_count` function from?

Answer (score 4):

You could solve your problem as follow:

```
colSums(sapply(words, stringi::stri_count_fixed, str=str_list))
# corn food 
#    2    1

# or 
stringi::stri_count_fixed(paste0(str_list, collapse=" "), words)
# [1] 2 1
```

###### data

```
str_list <- list("corn is food", "corn is good")
words <- c("corn", "food")
```

Comment: Amazing solution indeed

Answer (score 4):

With `base` R, You can use `sapply` + `grep` + `lengths`:

```r
lengths(sapply(words, grep, str_list))

# corn food 
#    2    1
```

---

###### Update

As @Onyambu points out, if a word is repeated in a sentence, `grep` will not capture the repeat. A revision is made by replacing `grep()` with `gregexpr()`.

```r
sapply(words, \(x) sum(gregexpr(x, toString(str_list))[[1]] > 0))
```

An equivalent solution with `stringr::str_count()`:

```r
colSums(sapply(words, stringr::str_count, string = str_list))
```

---

###### Data

```r
str_list <- list("corn is food", "corn is good")
words <- c("corn", "food")
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood properly what you need, the code below should solve it, although we do have `str_count` in there:

```
library(stringr)

str_list <- list("corn is food", "corn is good")
word_list <- c("corn", "food")

count_words <- function(string, words) {
  sum(sapply(words, function(word) str_count(string, word)))
}

result <- sapply(str_list, count_words, word_list)
```

which outputs the required vector:

```
> print(result)
[1] 2 1
```

Comment: You need to fix something! Please try this example: `str_list <- list("corn is good", "corn is good")`. There are 2 corns and 0 food, so the correct output should be `2 0`, but your code gets `1 1`, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `strsplit` + `table` like below

```
> table(unlist(strsplit(unlist(str_list), "\\W+")))[word_list]

corn food
   2    1
```